# __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM undefined when linking oracle's jvm from c++

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, mingw

Following [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#creating_the_vm) to create and invoke a JVM in c++, I'm having the  problem mentioned in the title when executing this command:

```
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -I "${JAVA_HOME}include" -I "${JAVA_HOME}include/win32" -L "${JAVA_HOME}lib" -L "${JAVA_HOME}jre/bin/server" -ljvm Main.cpp
```

I have checked that JAVA_HOME is correctly set. the exact output I'm getting is:

```
/tmp/ccFK8rea.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x5f): referencia a `__imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
```

I'm using Windows 8 64bits, mingw64 and the 64bits oracle's JDK

Comment: Is that the full error message, or does it complain that it doesn't find `libjvm` before that bit? Because I think that should be `-L "${JAVA_HOME}jre/lib/server"` instead of `-L "${JAVA_HOME}jre/bin/server"`.

Comment: That is the full error message. I have solved this problem by placing the -ljvm at the end of the command just after the Main.cpp.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense if it's linked statically. I'll leave this link, then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc